# Is it possible to force ignore the :hover pseudoclass for iPhone/iPad users?

Tags: ipad, mobile-safari, iphone, pseudo-class

I have some css menus on my site that expand with `:hover` (without js)

This works in a semi-broken way on iDevices, for example a tap will activate the `:hover` rule and expand the menu, but then tapping elsewhere doesn't remove the `:hover`. Also if there is a link inside the element that is `:hover`'ed, you have to tap twice to activate the link (first tap triggers `:hover`, second tap triggers link).

I've been able to make things work nicely on iphone by binding the `touchstart` event.

The problem is that sometimes mobile safari still chooses to trigger the `:hover` rule from the css *instead* of my `touchstart` events!

I know this is the problem because when I disable all the `:hover` rules manually in the css, mobile safari works great (but regular browsers obviously don't anymore).

Is there a way to dynamically "cancel" `:hover` rules for certain elements when the user is on mobile safari?

See and compare iOS behavior here: http://jsfiddle.net/74s35/3/
Note: that only some css properties trigger the two-click behavior, e.g. display:none; but not background: red; or text-decoration: underline;

Comment: PLEASE do NOT disable hovering just because of the presence of 'touch' events. This will adversely affect users of laptops that have touch and mouse input devices. See my answer for more details

Answer (score 77, accepted):

I found that ":hover" is unpredictable in iPhone/iPad Safari. Sometimes tap on element make that element ":hover", while sometimes it drifts to other elements.

For the time being, I just have a "no-touch" class at body.

```
<body class="yui3-skin-sam no-touch">
   ...
</body>
```

And have all CSS rules with ":hover" below ".no-touch":

```
.no-touch my:hover{
   color: red;
}
```

Somewhere in the page, I have javascript to remove **no-touch** class from body.

```
if ('ontouchstart' in document) {
    Y.one('body').removeClass('no-touch');
}
```

This doesn't look perfect, but it works anyway.

Comment: This is the only way to do it. What bothers me is that it pollutes the "normal" site with stuff that doesn't belong there and is irrelevant. Oh well. Thanks.

Comment: You could also use media queries with a fallback for IE

Comment: @morgancheng, I'm thinking that this doesn't really accomplish everything though.  Chris is losing his hover effect completely on touch devices now.  How can he (or I) force "one click" to activate the hover effect, and "second click" engage the link?  Further, the "click somewhere else" would then deactivate the hover effect accordingly. ?

Comment: @Shackrock: I don't think the "one tap to hover and two to click" approach is a good solution. Since there is in fact no actual hover on a touch device (until they come with screens that sense your finger hovering over it), I think it's better to not simulate hovering at all. For effects, like those common on buttons and links, just skip the effect. For menus that expand on hover, make them expand on tap/click instead. My 2c.

Comment: @AdrianSchmidt I do agree.  In my case, it's actually menus that need to expand on hover.  So, my intent of "one tap hover" (expand) applies only on the class where it's needed.  For other "hover effects," I don't apply the class and a click is simply a click (touchscreens just don't get the effects, as you state).

Comment: I've found issues recently in this sort of approach due to new Windows 8 systems featuring touch and mouse input

Comment: +1 to Tom's comment - checking for ontouchstart will return true on touch-capable laptops, even when plugged into an external monitor (where a mouse-friendly site with hover states is more desirable).

Comment: Breaks with newer browsers, Windows 8, and/or touchscreens, all of which are pretty common.

Comment: Solved using FastClick (Polyfill to remove click delays on browsers with touch UIs) — https://github.com/ftlabs/fastclick

Answer (score 48):

`:hover` isn't the issue here.  Safari for iOS follows a very odd rule.  It fires `mouseover` and `mousemove` first; if anything is changed during these events, 'click' and related events don't get fired:

[image: Diagram of touch event in iOS]

`mouseenter` and `mouseleave` appear to be included, though they're not specified in the chart.

If you modify anything as a result of these events, click events won't get fired.  That includes something higher up in the DOM tree.  For example, this will prevent single clicks from working on your website with jQuery:

```
$(window).on('mousemove', function() {
    $('body').attr('rel', Math.random());
});
```

Edit: For clarification, jQuery's `hover` event includes `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`.  These will both prevent `click` if content is changed.

Comment: of course :hover is the issue :-) or rather Safari's buggy implementation of it. this is interesting background on the issue, but Apple is the only party that can fix this terrible behavior. it either needs to 'unhover' when something outside the elements is clicked, or never 'hover' in the first place. the current behavior basically breaks any website that uses :hover for a mouse

Comment: this did help me realize that the jquery `hover` handler was preventing a separate `click` handler being hit - what a joke!

Comment: Brilliant answer, and best explanation of the problem I've come across. It's not just CSS hovers that cause the "double click" problem, but literally any DOM modification after the mouseover/mouseenter et al events.

Comment: Here is an example which shows the click event not firing when the DOM is modified on `mouseenter` http://jsbin.com/maseti/5/edit?html,js,output

Comment: @Oliver Joseph Ash Right, hence the JS example in the answer. ;)

Answer (score 29):

A better solution, without any JS, css class and viewport check: you can use Interaction Media Features [(Media Queries Level 4)](https://www.w3.org/TR/mediaqueries-4/#mf-interaction)

Like this:

```
@media (hover) {
  // properties
  my:hover {
    color: red;
  }
}
```

iOS Safari [supports it](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-media-interaction)

More about:
https://www.jonathanfielding.com/an-introduction-to-interaction-media-features/

Comment: Not supported by Firefox though (at the time of this comment of course)

Comment: This is now supported by Firefox, as well (FF 64+, released Dec 2018).

Comment: The accepted answer is from 2011, this is a much better approach in 2021. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/hover

Answer (score 18):

The browser feature detection library [**Modernizer**](http://modernizr.com/) includes a check for touch events.

It’s default behavior is to apply classes to your html element for each feature being detected. You can then use these classes to style your document.

If touch events are not enabled Modernizr can add a class of `no-touch`:

```
<html class="no-touch">
```

And then scope your hover styles with this class:

```
.no-touch a:hover { /* hover styles here */ }
```

You can [download a custom Modernizr build](http://modernizr.com/download/) to include as few or as many feature detections as you need.

Here's an example of some classes that may be applied:

```
<html class="js no-touch postmessage history multiplebgs
             boxshadow opacity cssanimations csscolumns cssgradients
             csstransforms csstransitions fontface localstorage sessionstorage
             svg inlinesvg no-blobbuilder blob bloburls download formdata">
```

Comment: Be aware that on recent versions of Chrome on desktops that Modernizr reports "touch".  This is apparently corrected in version 3 with touchevents.

Answer (score 18):

Some devices (as others have said) have both touch and mouse events. The Microsoft Surface for example has a touch screen, a trackpad AND a stylus which actually raises hover events when it is  hovered above the screen.

Any solution that disables `:hover` based on the presence of 'touch' events will also affect Surface users (and many other similar devices). Many new laptops are touch and will respond to touch events - so disabling hovering is a really bad practice.

This is a bug in Safari, there's absolutely no justification for this terrible behavior. I refuse to sabotage non iOS browsers because of a bug in iOS Safari which has apparently been there for years. I really hope they fix this for iOS8 next week but in  the meantime....

*My solution*:

Some have suggested using Modernizr already, well Modernizr allows you to create your own tests. What I'm basically doing here is 'abstracting' the idea of a browser that supports `:hover` into a Modernizr test that I can use throughout my code without hardcoding `if (iOS)` throughout.

```
 Modernizr.addTest('workinghover', function ()
 {
      // Safari doesn't 'announce' to the world that it behaves badly with :hover
      // so we have to check the userAgent  
      return navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPad|iPhone|iPod)/g) ? false : true;
 });
```

Then the css becomes something like this

```
html.workinghover .rollover:hover 
{
    // rollover css
}
```

Only on iOS will this test fail and disable rollover.

The best part of such abstraction is that if I find it breaks on a certain android or if it's fixed in iOS9 then I can just modify the test.

Comment: This solution is both nasty and the best out there. It only breaks if a browser that struggles with hover has both touch and click, but for the touch-only browsers on ipad/iphone this is not the case.

My suggestion is to implement this only as an optimisation fix (to remove hover flickering when already using fastclick.js) and make sure everything also works without it.

Comment: Thanks. I agree. Curious to see what iOS 9 does for this issue - if anything.

Comment: I went the opposite direction: `html:not(.no-hover) .category:hover { ...`

Comment: +1 for "Safari doesn't 'announce' to the world that it behaves badly with :hover" This issue makes iOS way worse than any version of IE in my opinion...

Comment: This is still occurring today. I've just spent a good hour googling answers and there doesn't seem to be a globally accepted "best solution" to this. Yet it's now 2022, 5 years after the last comment, and it's still a problem..... Why Apple, why make our lives harder than it needs to be.

Answer (score 16):

Adding the [FastClick library](https://github.com/ftlabs/fastclick) to your page will cause all taps on a mobile device to be turned into click events (regardless of where the user clicks), so it should also fix the hover issue on mobile devices.  I edited your fiddle as an example: http://jsfiddle.net/FvACN/8/.

Just include the fastclick.min.js lib on your page, and activate via:

```
FastClick.attach(document.body);
```

As a side benefit, it will also remove the annoying 300ms onClick delay that mobile devices suffer from.

There are a couple of minor consequences to using FastClick that may or may not matter for your site:

1. If you tap somewhere on the page, scroll up, scroll back down, and then release your finger on the exact same position that you initially placed it, FastClick will interpret that as a "click", even though it's obviously not. At least that's how it works in the version of FastClick that I'm currently using (1.0.0). Someone may have fixed the issue since that version.
2. FastClick removes the ability for someone to "double click".

Comment: Would you be willing to share another concrete example of how I can do this for my website.  I don't know anything about javascript so I'm a little confused about how this would work.  I have all these links on my website that users usually hover over before clicking, but for ipad/mobile I want to make it so that they don't have to click twice.

Comment: @Andy - It's not exactly clear what you need and what you're missing... What have you tried, so far, and what errors are you seeing, if any?  Maybe it would be best to create a new Stackoverflow question, if you haven't already, with an example of what you're trying to do(?)  Or try to clarify what it is in the above, jsfiddle example that you don't understand.

Comment: can this be used in single page applications? I mean when DOM content is updated everytime

Comment: Yes, I'm using it with single-page applications.

Answer (score 4):

There are basically three scenarios:

1. User *only* has a mouse/pointer device and can activate `:hover`
2. User *only* has a touchscreen, and can not activate `:hover` elements
3. User has *both* a touchscreen and a pointer device

The originally accepted answer works great if only the first two scenarios are possible, where a user has *either* pointer or touchscreen. This was common when the OP asked the question 4 years ago. Several users have pointed out that Windows 8 and Surface devices are making the third scenario more likely.

The iOS solution to the problem of not being able to hover on touchscreen devices (as detailed by @Zenexer) is clever, but can cause straightforward code to misbehave (as noted by the OP). Disabling hover only for touchscreen devices means that you will still need to code a touchscreen friendly alternative. Detecting when a user has both pointer and touchscreen further muddies the waters (as explained by @Simon_Weaver).

At this point, the safest solution is to avoid using `:hover` as the only way a user can interact with your website. Hover effects are a good way of indicating that a link or button is actionable, but a user should not be required to hover an element to perform an action on your website.

[Re-thinking “hover” functionality with touchscreens in mind](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/14257/re-thinking-hover-functionality-with-touchscreens-in-mind) has a good discussion about alternative UX approaches. The solutions provided by the answer there include:

- Replacing hover menus with direct actions (always visible links)
- Replacing on-hover menus with on-tap menus
- Moving large amounts of on-hover content into a separate page

Moving forward, this will probably be the best solution for all new projects. The accepted answer is probably the second best solution, but be sure to account for devices that also have pointer devices. Be careful not to eliminate functionality when a device has a touchscreen just to work around iOS's `:hover` hack.

Answer (score 1):

The JQuery version
in your .css use 
  .no-touch .my-element:hover
for all your hover rules
include JQuery and the following script

```
function removeHoverState(){
    $("body").removeClass("no-touch");
}
```

Then in body tag add
 class="no-touch" ontouchstart="removeHoverState()"

as soon as the ontouchstart fires the class for all hover states is removed

Answer (score 1):

I agree disabling hover for touch is the way to go.

However, to save yourself the trouble of re-writing your css, just wrap any `:hover` items in  `@supports not (-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch) {}`

```css
.hover, .hover-iOS {
  display:inline-block;
  font-family:arial;
  background:red;
  color:white;
  padding:5px;
}
.hover:hover {
  cursor:pointer;
  background:green;
}

.hover-iOS {
  background:grey;
}

@supports not (-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch) {
  .hover-iOS:hover {
    cursor:pointer;
    background:blue;
  }

}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="hover" placeholder="Hover over me" />

<input type="text" class="hover-iOS" placeholder="Hover over me (iOS)" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of only having hover effects when touch is not available I created a system for handling touch events and that has solved the problem for me. First, I defined an object for testing for "tap" (equivalent to "click") events.

```
touchTester = 
{
    touchStarted: false
   ,moveLimit:    5
   ,moveCount:    null
   ,isSupported:  'ontouchend' in document

   ,isTap: function(event)
   {
      if (!this.isSupported) {
         return true;
      }

      switch (event.originalEvent.type) {
         case 'touchstart':
            this.touchStarted = true;
            this.moveCount    = 0;
            return false;
         case 'touchmove':
            this.moveCount++;
            this.touchStarted = (this.moveCount <= this.moveLimit);
            return false;
         case 'touchend':
            var isTap         = this.touchStarted;
            this.touchStarted = false;
            return isTap;
         default:
            return true;
      }
   }
};
```

Then, in my event handler I do something like the following:

```
$('#nav').on('click touchstart touchmove touchend', 'ul > li > a'
            ,function handleClick(event) {
               if (!touchTester.isTap(event)) {
                  return true;
               }

               // touch was click or touch equivalent
               // nromal handling goes here.
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Morgan Cheng for the answer, however I've slightly modified the JS function for getting the "*touchstart*" (code taken from @Timothy Perez [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4755505/how-to-recognize-touch-events-using-jquery-in-safari-for-ipad-is-it-possible)), though, you need jQuery 1.7+ for this

```
  $(document).on({ 'touchstart' : function(){
      //do whatever you want here
    } });
```

Answer (score 0):

Given the response provided by Zenexer, a pattern that requires no additional HTML tags is:

```
jQuery('a').on('mouseover', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    // Show and hide your drop down nav or other elem
});
jQuery('a').on('click', function(event) {
    if (jQuery(event.target).children('.dropdown').is(':visible') {
        // Hide your dropdown nav here to unstick
    }
});
```

This method fires off the mouseover first, the click second.

Answer (score 0):

For those with common use case of disabling `:hover` events on iOS Safari, the simplest way is to use a min-width media query for your `:hover` events which stays above the screen width of the devices you are avoiding. Example:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
  .my-div:hover { // will only work on devices larger than iOS touch-enabled devices. Will still work on touch-enabled PCs etc.
    background-color: red;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For someone still looking for a solution if none of the above worked,

Try this,

```
@media (hover: hover)
{
    .Link:hover
    {
        color:#00d8fe;
    }
}
```

This hover pseudo will only be applied for devices with pointers and works normal on touch devices with just .active classes.

Answer (score -6):

Just look at the screen size....

```
@media (min-width: 550px) {
    .menu ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}
}
```

Answer (score -12):

heres the code you'll want to place it in

```
// a function to parse the user agent string; useful for 
// detecting lots of browsers, not just the iPad.
function checkUserAgent(vs) {
    var pattern = new RegExp(vs, 'i');
    return !!pattern.test(navigator.userAgent);
}
if ( checkUserAgent('iPad') ) {
    // iPad specific stuff here
}
```