# Is there a tap and double tap event in d3.js force directed graph

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, d3.js, force-layout

I am working on a force directed graph using d3.js. I need to handle tap and double tap event on nodes for mobile devices. Mouseover and click functions need to replicated as tap and double tap in d3.js. I have managed to get a touch event working but have no clue on how to capture double tap event in a mobile device.

Comment: i think you should check this post   
 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5507638/whats-the-best-way-to-handle-longtap-and-double-tap-events-on-mobile-devices-us

Answer (score 5, accepted):

D3 has the  [touches event](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-d3_touches) and using this you can get touch position coordinates from inside your event handler, but this doesn't give you any special handling for or help identify long press and doubletap.  You can add support for long press and double tap yourself. For long press, have a look at this example:

[Long Press in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2625210/long-press-in-javascript)

If you're using jQuery, there are doubletap plugins like this one:

[jQuery doubletap plugin](http://appcropolis.com/implementing-doubletap-on-iphones-and-ipads)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no double tap in d3, so as suggested before, you got to work with touchstart. [Here is how](http://bl.ocks.org/jczaplew/7018691)