# Stop event.preventDefault being applied to all links

Tags: html, jquery, jquery-events

I have a CSS menu hover that isn't working on iPad. Looking around I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15973869/css-only-drop-down-menu-doesnt-like-ipad-etc-follows-menu-link-without-reveali) on Stack Overflow. To trigger the hover I have set up an `event.preventDefault` on the top level links which is working great. However this being applied to all links under the menu which means you cant navigate around the website.

I have created a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vbooqprj/).

How can I make it so that anything with a class `.menu-item-has-children` the event is prevented but for any other `<a></a>` under that class is works.

**Unfortunately/annoyingly** its not possible to edit the HTML markup

Here is my code:

**HTML**

```
<nav id="top-menu">
<ul>
    <li class="menu-item-has-children"><a>Link 1</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="http://www.google.co.uk">Google</a></li>
            <li class="menu-item-has-children"><a href="http://www.google.co.uk">Google</a>
                <ul>
                   <li><a href="#">Google 1</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#">Google 1</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#">Google 1</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#">Google 1</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Google</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Google</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-item-has-children"><a>Link 2</a>
       <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Google</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Google</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Google</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Google</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-item-has-children"><a>Link 3</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Google</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Google</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Google</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Google</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-item-has-children"><a>Link 4</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Google</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Google</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Google</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Google</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$("#top-menu .menu-item-has-children a").click(function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log('clicked');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `>` ([CSS Direct Descendant Selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors)):

```
$("#top-menu .menu-item-has-children > a").click(function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log('clicked');
});
```

That selects only`<a/>` tags that are a direct descendant of `menu-item-has-children`.

So for example, in this code block, it selects the 'Link 2' anchor, but not any 'Google' anchor:

```
<li class="menu-item-has-children"><a>Link 2</a>
   <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Google</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Google</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Google</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Google</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```