# Jquery mobile touch event randomly recognised

Tags: javascript, api, jquery-mobile, touch

I want to do an action on recognition of touch event of IPAD.
The issue is that the touch event is being invoked more than once even if the touch is done once.

```
handleEvent: function (e) {
var that = this;
//console.log("---------------------------------handle event ");
switch(e.type) {
case START_EV:
if (!hasTouch && e.button !== 0) return;
that._start(e);
break;
case MOVE_EV: that._move(e); break;
case END_EV:
case CANCEL_EV: that._end(e); break;
case RESIZE_EV: that._resize(); break;
case 'mouseout': that._mouseout(e); break;
case 'webkitTransitionEnd': that._transitionEnd(e); break;
}
}
```

---

How to recognise the event only once.

Thanks,
Vaibhav

Answer (score 0):

jQuery doesn't have anything special for touch events, but you can easily build your own using the following events

touchstart
touchmove
touchend
touchcancel

For example, the touchmove (Taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4755505/how-to-recognize-touch-events-using-jquery-in-safari-for-ipad-is-it-possible))

document.addEventListener('touchmove', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var touch = e.touches[0];
    alert(touch.pageX + " - " + touch.pageY);
}, false);