# jquery touchmove chrome mobile

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, touchmove

How can i get the id of the elements under my finger during touchmove?

What i want to achieve is:

- bind touch[start|end|move]
- on touchstart start selection
- during touchmove collect all dom elements "touched" under my finger

example code

```
var collected = [];
$('body').bind('touchstart touchmove touchend', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  if(event.type == 'touchstart') {
    collected = [];
  } else if(event.type == 'touchmove') {
    // id of the element under my finger??
    // insert in collected the id of the element
  } else if(event.type == 'touchend') {
    // some code
  }
});
```

solved.

Comment: @Daneb: how did you solve this in the end, can you post your solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can find information about all touch events in Safari [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/appleapplications/reference/safariwebcontent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html). jQuery does not have any touch event handlers, you would need to define them yourselve. Taken from [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4755505/how-to-recognize-touch-events-using-jquery-in-safari-for-ipad-is-it-possible)

```
document.addEventListener('touchmove', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var touch = e.touches[0];
    alert(touch.pageX + " - " + touch.pageY);
}, false);
```

This way you could define your way through all touch gestures.

Comment: touchstart and touchend are fired correctly; should be the same for touchmove, or not?

Comment: yes, this should be the case. else you are dealing with a bug

Comment: ok, now i can get the touched [x,y] coords, how can i locate the elements?

Comment: ok, now i can get the element id with $(document.elementFromPoint(touch.pageX, touch.pageY)), it workd fine in the default android browser and opera; but not in Chrome; any advice to fix it? It seems that it find the element at "different" positions