# How do I get touch coordinates in iOS Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mobile-safari

I am using the below code to get the touch coordinates in iOS Safari

```
$('#touchable').bind('touchstart', function(e){

        alert(e.touches[0].pageX);
        alert(e.touches[0].pageY);
}
```

But when I test it I am unable to get the coordinates. 
Is this code the right way to get the touch coordinates ?

Comment: Sometimes `e.targetTouches[0].pageX` works *I think*

Comment: @Derek Tried that too. Still not working :(

Answer (score 3):

Prefer the following link :

[Detect Safari Touch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4755505/how-to-recognize-touch-events-using-jquery-in-safari-for-ipad-is-it-possible)

and try this code

```
document.addEventListener('touchmove', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var touch = e.touches[0];
    alert(touch.pageX + " - " + touch.pageY);
}, false);
```

to add touchEvent.

Comment: e.touches[0] is not working on Safari iOS Mobile