# click event is not working in ipad

Tags: ipad, click

Here is my code:

```
     var tmp = plugin.main_video_src.split("_")[1]

     if(tmp == 2)
     {
        $('.flex-direction-nav .flex-next').click();
     }
```

This works perfectly in PC browser, But its not working in iPad. Any solution?

Advance Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

It could be because you're trying to react to events on an html element that isn't clickable.  [This tutorial will explain how](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006511-SW6)

> ## Making Elements Clickable
>
> Because of the way Safari on iOS creates events to emulate a mouse, some of your elements may not behave as expected on iOS. In particular, some menus that only use mousemove handlers, as in Listing 6-1, need to be changed because iOS doesn’t recognize them as clickable elements.
>
> Listing 6-1  A menu using a mouseover handler

```
<span onmouseover = "..."
  onmouseout  = "..."
 
WHERE TO BUY
 
</span>
```

> To fix this, add a dummy onclick handler, `onclick = "void(0)"`, so that Safari on iOS recognizes the span element as a clickable element, as shown in Listing 6-2.
>
> Listing 6-2  Adding an onclick handler

```
<span onmouseover = "..."
  onmouseout  = "..."
  onclick = "void(0)">
 
WHERE TO BUY
 
</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

I used "**touchstart**" event instead of "**click**" event. It works perfectly for me.
Here is the sample code :

```
$("<selector>").bind("touchstart", function() {

// YOUR CODE ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

OnClick event doesn't exist on the IPad. You need the touch event

```
$('.flex-direction-nav .flex-next').trigger('touchstart');

document.addEventListener('touchstart', function(e) {
    //Bind your event here
}, false);
```

You have the following events

> 1. touchstart
> 2. touchmove
> 3. touchend
> 4. touchcancel

[How to recognize touch events using jQuery in Safari for iPad? Is it possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4755505/how-to-recognize-touch-events-using-jquery-in-safari-for-ipad-is-it-possible)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue. This is what worked for me.

```
$('.flex-direction-nav .flex-next').off('click').on('click');
```