# Click listener on iPhone / iPad

Tags: jquery, html, ios, click

In a PC, Mac and any Android device, when you click or touch an image, the showItem function is called, and I display the image in full screen mode.

However, **when I test this in Iphone / iPad, when you first touch the image, the hover event is fired, and you need to touch another time to actually activate the function**. How can I overcome this?

**jQuery**

```
this1.on("click", function(evt){ 
    evt.preventDefault();
    evt.stopPropagation();
    showItem(this1);
});
```

PS: the this1 variable, is the img with the .item class below

**HTML / PHP**

```
<div class='galleryImage'>
    <span class='hidden' title='images/galleries/".$category."/".$dir[$i]."' ></span>
    <img class='item image' src='images/galleries/".$category."/".$dir[$i]."' alt='image-jpg' />
    <img src='images/ajax-small.gif' class='galleryLoader' alt='galleryLoader' />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [`tap`](http://api.jquerymobile.com/tap/). Make sure you load [jQuery mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/download/) as well.

```
this1.on("tap", function() {
    // your function here
});
```

See also

- [How to recognize touch events using jQuery in Safari for iPad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4755505/how-to-recognize-touch-events-using-jquery-in-safari-for-ipad-is-it-possible)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, however, when I try to add jQuery mobile in my website, markup is added to most elements in my page, and the layout breaks.

Comment: @ΝίκοςΡουσσουνέλος Do not use the stylesheet. Just add `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.js"></script>`.