# Menu not animating on Ipad

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I´m working on this [website](http://thelovemonster.net/index2.php/):

The navigation works well on mac chrome and other browsers.

For example if you **click on Blog**, it goes to blog and hides the menu after you leave the mouse from it.

The problem is that on **Ipad and Iphone** the menu keeps **open always**, any ideas why?

This is my code for animation:

```
    function Main_menu() {
        _menu = this;
        _menu.pw_protected_target = '';
        _menu.container = $('#header');
        _menu.logo = $('#logo');
        _menu.menu = $('#menu');
        _menu.form = $('#login');
        _menu.form_input = $('#form_input');
        _menu.form_submit = $('#submit')
        _menu.container.bind({
            'mouseenter' : _menu.open,
            'mouseleave' : _menu.close
        });
        _menu.form_submit.bind('click', function(){
            _menu.authenticate(_menu.form_input.val())
        })
        $('.tt').bind({
            'mouseenter' : function(){
                $('.tooltip')
                .addClass('fade in')
                .css({
                    'top' : $(this).offset().top - 5,
                    'left' : $(this).offset().left + $(this).width() + 10
                })
            },
            'mouseleave' : function(){
                $('.tooltip')
                .removeClass('fade in');
            }
        })

        $('.tt_shop').bind({
            'mouseenter' : function(){
                $('.tooltip_shop')
                .addClass('fade in')
                .css({
                    'top' : $(this).offset().top - 5,
                    'left' : $(this).offset().left + $(this).width() + 10
                })
            },
            'mouseleave' : function(){
                $('.tooltip_shop')
                .removeClass('fade in');
            }
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you attached the mouse correctly on your iPad? :)

There are no 'mouseenter' or 'mouseleave' events on touch-devices. Unfortunately jQuery core has no touch events. You could use some of the proposals I found in this thread:

[How to recognize touch events using jQuery in Safari for iPad? Is it possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4755505/how-to-recognize-touch-events-using-jquery-in-safari-for-ipad-is-it-possible)

I think in your case it would be best to change the behaviour of your menu to toggle show/hide the menu on touch.

Comment: :) and how can I control it then on those devices? what would be a quick way?