# UIPageViewController - How do I capture touch points?

Tags: ios, uipageviewcontroller

This is simple. I have an iBooks-like app that has a UIPageViewController as a child viewController. When the page curl kicks in, how do I capture the user's touch point/s? I wish to continually track finger locations while the curl is visible.

Comment: not exactly sure what you are asking but you may want to take a look at this post - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4755505/how-to-recognize-touch-events-using-jquery-in-safari-for-ipad-is-it-possible

Comment: @1337holiday, no good. :-)