# Swap background images on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I create a animation that works when I hover over it, but due to mobile reasons I want the animation to play when the user clicks or touches it.

Here is my js code that makes the hover work, but not sure how to make the onclick work.

```
$(document).ready(function() {     
    $('.phone').hover(function(){     
        $('.phone').addClass('phone-two');    
    },     
    function(){    
        $('.phone').removeClass('phone-two');     
    });
});
```

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/daugaard47/gQLPr/) to explain it better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To bind all of your events, use this:

```
$('.phone').on("mouseover click touchstart touchend",function(){
    $('.phone').toggleClass('phone-two');    
});
```

Reference: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: Thanks that made the click work, but how can I click again to turn off the animation?

Comment: Use ```toggleClass``` instead of ```addClass``` : $('.phone').toggleClass('phone-two');

Answer (score 2):

With [`$.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) you can add the `'touchstart'` and `'touchend'` event.

```
$(document).ready(function() {     
$('.phone').on({
    'mouseover touchstart': function(){     
         $('.phone').addClass('phone-two');    
     },     
     'mouseout touchend': function(){    
         $('.phone').removeClass('phone-two');     
    }});
});
```

note that this also preserves your hover event.

here is a great post on mobile touch events: [How to recognize touch events using jQuery in Safari for iPad? Is it possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4755505/how-to-recognize-touch-events-using-jquery-in-safari-for-ipad-is-it-possible)

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/gQLPr/3/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$('.phone').on('click', function (e) {  
    $('.phone').toggleClass('phone-two');  
});
```

Comment: Just curious what is the (e) stand for or do?

Comment: It's the jQuery event object. Read through the docs to get some fundamentals, it helps! http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/