# How do I get touch events (Hammer) on general HTML elements?

Tags: onsen-ui

I have a DIV inside a page element of a sliding menu / navigator. I'm trying to capture Hammer events on this element but am only able to access "touch" events.

```
var hammer = Hammer(getElementById('myDiv'));
hammer.on('touch swipe', function(e){
   console.log(e); 
});
```

Is there something I'm missing, or does Onsen UI set specific things with Hammer that is interfering?

Comment: check this related topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4755505/how-to-recognize-touch-events-using-jquery-in-safari-for-ipad-is-it-possible

Comment: Thanks, .hammer({prevent_default: true}) seemed to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you cancel default touch event? It worked for me.

```
var element = document.querySelector('.your-div');

element.ontouchmove = function(event) {
    if (!event.elementIsEnabled) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
};

element.ontouchstart = function(event) {
    if (!event.elementIsEnabled) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
};

element.ontouchend = function(event) {
    if (!event.elementIsEnabled) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
};

var hammertime = Hammer(element).on("swiperight", function(event) {
    //do stuff
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I think this makes sense. From the above I found that adding .hammer({prevent_default: true}) worked.

Is this because the events are already being captured and stop propagating?