# Apply css property hover, ontouch in mobile devices

Tags: html, css, sass

Below is the link of codePen, you can see if its window size then image get border on hover,

In mobile devices it get border on touch. but it doesn't go away if user is not touching it (after touching it). user needs to touch outside the image then its border goes away.

In the below image, user touch the image and its showing border, later user is not touching it and its still showing border.
[image]

```css
 .swap {
  background-image: url('https://farm9.staticflickr.com/8382/8558295631_0f56c1284f_b.jpg');
  width: 200px;
}

.swap a {
  display: block;
}

.swap a img {

  width: 200px;
  height: auto;


}
.swap a:hover img {
  border:10px black solid;
}

.swap a:focus img {
  border:none !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="swap">
  <a>
    <img src="https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/undertale-au/images/5/54/Link.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20170903211129">
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: https://codepen.io/SahilKatia/pen/GBGEXa

Comment: FYI, hover not working in mobile/touch device to handle hover event you need touch event using javascript or jQuery just like [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4755505/how-to-recognize-touch-events-using-jquery-in-safari-for-ipad-is-it-possible]

Comment: thanks, just now I found this out too, using touchstart and touchend together on one element  will solve my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I solved this question by JavaScript events,ontouchstart and  ontouchend please check out the below plunkr link

https://plnkr.co/edit/bVFQMUjJXo5SvLGroQH3?p=preview

```
function myFunction()
{
    document.getElementById('swap').setAttribute("class", "style1");
}

function myFunctions()
{
    document.getElementById('swap').setAttribute("class", "style2");
}



 <div id="swap">
  <a><img src="https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/undertale-au/images/5/54/Link.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20170903211129" ontouchstart="myFunction()" ontouchend="myFunctions()"   >
      </a>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding the `:focus` pseudo class will work for you to override what is happening.

```
.swap a:hover img {
  border:10px black solid;
}

.swap a:focus img {
  border:none !important;
}
```

If you are working on a responsive project that you do not want `:focus` to show on non-touch devices you can try to target devices by size, or more reliably, you could use Modernizr to feature detect.

Comment: its still there

Comment: I'm sorry... I completely misread your question. I thought you wanted to know how to add it. Editing my answer now.

Comment: I updated the codepen with your code,but its not working, in mobile view if I touch this then it takes the border, later if i am not touching it border is still there

Comment: Take a look at my revised answer now. ;)

Comment: user needs to touch outside the image then its border goes away.( we dont want this feature). if the user is not touching it , it shouldn't show border

Comment: I added screenshot to explain more please check it

Comment: this.primaryPhone.number.value.
      replace('(', '').replace(')', '').replace('-', '').replace(/ /g, '').replace(/_/g, ''))

Answer (score 0):

Prepared for another query, just replace P with your element.
It now seems best to avoid using hover altogether with ios or touch in general. The below code applies your css as long as touch is maintained, and without other ios flyouts. Do this;

1. Jquery add: $("p").on("touchstart", function(e) { $(this).focus(); e.preventDefault(); });
2. CSS: replace p:hover with p:focus, and add p:active

Options;

- replace jquery p selector with any class etc
- to have the effect remain, keep p:hover as well, and add body{cursor:ponter;} so a tap anywhere ends it
- try click & mouseover events as well as touchstart in same code (but not tested)
- remove e.preventDefault(); to enable users to utilise ios flyouts eg copy

Notes

- only tested for text elements, ios may treat inputs etc differently
- only tested on iphone XR ios 12.1.12, and ipad 3 ios 9.3.5, using Safari or Chrome.