# Based on touch screen and keyboard detection,implement different functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I created a custom Navbar which is working perfectly. My problem lies within which functionality to use based on the device in action. For touchscreen devices I would like to use the click function, and for keyboard devices hover. I have two scripts both for hover and click events for my Navbar.

Click

```
<script>
$( '.tc-navigation > li' ).click(function() {
$(this).children('ul').toggleClass('toto');
$(this).siblings().children('ul').removeClass('toto');   
return false;
});

$(document).click(function() {
$('.tc-navigation > li > ul').removeClass('toto');
});
</script>
```

For Hover

```
<script>
$( '.tc-navigation > li' ).hover(function() {
$(this).children('ul').toggleClass('toto');   
});
</script>
```

Can anybody please assist how I can figure out the type of device used as well as how to implement the already written scripts at hand?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to recognize touch events using jQuery in Safari for iPad? Is it possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4755505/how-to-recognize-touch-events-using-jquery-in-safari-for-ipad-is-it-possible)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. First, you need a way to detect, whether device is mobile or not:

   ```
   function isMobile() {
     return /Mobile/.test(navigator.userAgent); // do some research if "Mobile" always occurs in userAgent string if you want to be sure
   }
   ```
2. Based on that you can choose your event:

   ```
   var event = isMobile() ? "click" : "mouseover";
   ```
3. Use `event` variable to attach proper listener. In vanilla JS you would do something like this:

   ```
   element.addEventListener(event, doStuff);
   ```

I don't use jQuery, so I'll leave that for you to figure out, but i think what you would look for here is `.on()` method - [read here](http://api.jquery.com/on/)