# What is the best/easiest way to swipe (left-right) among images on mobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to create an interaction that lets the user swipe (right-left) among images on mobile. 
I'm using Jquery and I would like to stay with it. I know about jquery mobile, but if I can avoid it, it's better. 
If I have no option, I would use it anyway.

I tried many things and looked for answers, but nothing seems to fulfill my needs.

My ambition is to have the website do something when I swipe right or left. 
Something similiar to what I achieve with the 'mousewheel' event, but on mobile a with right-left swipe (instead of the mousewheel).

I will really appreciate any suggestion

Comment: Are you trying to implement a carousel, or simply to catch the swipe event ?

Comment: I think [TouchSwipe](https://github.com/mattbryson/TouchSwipe-Jquery-Plugin) suitable for you.

Comment: @sebastienbarbier Actually, I'm just trying to catch the swipe event so latter I can add some changes (not necessarily carousel).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like [Hammer.js](https://hammerjs.github.io/) is what you are looking for. It also include a [jQuery plugin](https://hammerjs.github.io/jquery-plugin/)

Not using any dependencies, you can listen to events `touchstart, touchmove, touchend, touchcancel`: [How to recognize touch events using jQuery in Safari for iPad? Is it possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4755505/how-to-recognize-touch-events-using-jquery-in-safari-for-ipad-is-it-possible#4755579)

Comment: Can't I just do it with vanilla Javascript or Jquery? I thought I was easier.... I'm working on someones project and I don't think that installing Hammer is best option. Still, thanks, if there is no alternative, I'll consider that one.

Comment: You will need to listen manually all events, not the best I would avoid and add 7kb of dependancies for such things. There is options, I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Basic jQuery doesn't provide swipe options, you can either use jQuery mobile or ionic (you can include just the js part). I have used both for my hybrid apps but I felt ionic is better in performance and easy to implement.