# CSS :hover in Safari on iPhone and iPad clashes with added classes on click

Tags: css, iphone, ipad, safari, less

First thing is, I can only edit the `CSS/LESS` portion of the code.

I've encountered a problem, there's a span that has a background color added on `:hover` and a different background upon clicking it, where it gets a class .active via JS.

Problem is, on iPad and iPhone on first tap it activates the `:hover` styles, a secondary tap is required to turn on the added class `.active`. Anyone knows how to ignore the `:hover` style and go straight to adding a class?

Much appreciated!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to force ignore the :hover pseudoclass for iPhone/iPad users?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2741816/is-it-possible-to-force-ignore-the-hover-pseudoclass-for-iphone-ipad-users)

Answer (score 0):

Place all your :hover rules in a @media block:

```css
@media (hover: hover) {
    a:hover { color: blue; }
}
```

Comment: Hmm, it doesn't seem to be working. Either I am doing something wrong or some other styles (there's three levels of stylesheets) are still interfering. Nevertheless, thank you!

Comment: alternatively, you can override all your hover rules by adding

@media (hover: none) {
    your-element:hover { color: inherit; }
}

Answer (score 0):

Do this

```css
a:hover {
  background-color: transparent !important; /* If it works without adding !important, then do that. It's best to avoid !important */
}
```

```html
<a href="#">Focus</a>
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but this would only change the background to a transparent color, not disable the :hover.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a known issue. Please check "https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/getting-started/#support-sticky-hover-mobile" for more details. Few of the possible solutions to solve the above problem is "http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/sticky-hover-issue-solutions.shtml"

Comment: Yeah, so basically there's nothing to be done? It's a known issue with no solution - the ones in the second link require editing files I have no access to.

Comment: The link "http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/sticky-hover-issue-solutions.shtml" does mention few of the solutions (javascript, though) but you can use any one of the way to make hover states handled.

Comment: That's what I meant by "editing files I have no access to" - as I've specified in the main post, I can only use CSS/LESS, as it's a part of an authoring tool and I only have access to those parts, using javascript, jQuery and other such solutions is out of my reach.

Comment: I am sorry, I missed "First thing is, I can only edit the CSS/LESS portion of the code." With CSS, no solution is there to the best of my knowledge.