# Hover bug in Safari mobile cured by adding ontouchstart (!!)

Tags: css, ipad, safari, hover, ontouchstart

I am experiencing some very strange behaviour with :hover on li in mobile Safari (iPad).

Randomly :hover doesn't fire on *some* of the li's and this random behaviour actually changes over time - esp after a screen rotation.

Amazingly adding 'ontouchstart=""' to the lis completely cures this.

Any ideas why this solves the issue?  An explanation would help me ensure this works across browsers and give me hints towards necessary js fillins.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to force ignore the :hover pseudoclass for iPhone/iPad users?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2741816/is-it-possible-to-force-ignore-the-hover-pseudoclass-for-iphone-ipad-users)

Comment: Will remove my answer (but here's the link to [summarizing blog post](https://dev.webonomic.nl/fixing-the-iphone-css-hover-problem-on-ios), as the duplicate thread has a comprehensive explanation of both what's happening and how to avoid the negative effects.